# Passing array values to js

Tags: javascript, php

So current setup is as following:

**PHP:data.php**

```
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$data = array(
    "16508",
    "16498",
    "16506" 
);
if ($method === "GET") {    
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

**JS:**

```
$.get("./page_asset/data.php").then(function(returned) {
        data = JSON.parse(returned);    
};
```

Now, how do I parse the data without getting the specific php page (as I don't want to rely on the specific php address such as "/page-asset/data.php").

**For example:**

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  $data = array(
    "16508",
    "16498",
    "16506" 
   );   
?>
```

I simply want to pass these values to js without relying on the page url.

Comment: What do you mean pass these values to js without relying on the page url? Why don't you just hardcode these values then?

Comment: Well, these values are dynamically generated. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP to create the Javascript in the original page. `json_encode()` can be used to convert a PHP value to the analogous JS literal.

```
<?php
  $data = array(
    "16508",
    "16498",
    "16506" 
   );   
?>
<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: This makes sense. And I can just use the variable `data` in js. Thanks! I will give it a try! =)

Comment: Just a quick question. Is there a way to make the values not visible in the element inspect? the `echo` is showing all the values from the frontend and was wondering if there is a way to hide the values.

Comment: Nope. The whole point was to put it into the Javascript, and everything in Javascript is visible in the client.

Comment: If you want to hide the data, you have to keep it on the server, and send a request to the server.

Comment: Your question said you didn't want to send an AJAX request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden field:

```
<input id="my-data" type="hidden" value='<?php echo json_encode($data)?>' />
```

And then you can parse the input value from javascript:

```
var data = $.parseJSON($('#my-data').val());
```

Comment: You should use single quotes around the value, because JSON uses double quotes around strings.