# How do we encode quotes in key of element for json_enode in PHP to be properly decoded by JSON.parse in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, json

In my PHP script, I have a variable that represents pairs of characters to be converted, among them quote (") to stripped quote (")

```
$a = [
    '"'=> '\"',
];
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**  This question had been marked a duplicate of [Passing array values to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320488/passing-array-values-to-js) .  However, the question here deals specifically with escaping quotes when converting to JSON, which the related question does not.

To pass this on to JavaScript, I embed this variable into an inline script.

```
var a = JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($a) ?>');
```

or

```
var a = <?= json_encode($a) ?>;
```

The problem is that, after the line is rendered as

```
var a = JSON.parse('{"\"":"\\\""}');
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 1 column 4 of the JSON data
```

How do I encode such data so that the original key and value will be properly passed to JavaScript with an error?

Comment: Your second version without `JSON.parse()` should work.

Comment: If the first version, you would have to double backslashes inside the Javascript string: `var a = JSON.parse('{"\\"":"\\\\\\""}');`

Comment: In PHP you don't need to escape `"` inside `''`.

Comment: You could try var a = `JSON.parse(\`<?= json_encode($a) ?>\`);`. Of course, that'd break if your JSON contains backticks.

Comment: `var a = <?= json_encode($a) ?>;` looks like it works fine?  https://3v4l.org/kNa1j - and then https://jsfiddle.net/qbp5um1o/ . No syntax errors.

Comment: You need to understand that when you type or copy/paste strings into code of any programming language that you are almost never inputting a literal string. Every language's compiler and interpreter have different rules according to which strings defined in source. Most relevant to your problem is escaping where JS is processing those escape sequences differently than you expect. If you were to make an actual AJAX request the code will likely work exactly as you expect.